# Is it possible to get Bitset to print bits to a single line?

Tags: c++, fstream, bitset

Im trying to have bitset convert a string into binary but only on one line, not multiple.

Ive been trying to put a username and password into binary to be stored in a file which could then be read later and put into text and checked.

I found this on the internet on bitset but dont know how to put it on one line.

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < UaP.size(); i++)
        {
            DataBase << bitset<8>(UaP.c_str()[i]) << endl;
        }
```

What I get is all the text on several lines

but im trying to get it to be 011000010010000000101100001000000110000100111011.
(All on one line)

Comment: `endl` stands for "end line", you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`endl` means end line, or insert the newline character (and incidentally it also flushes the stream).

Remove the `endl` if you don't want to do this.